# Nested List structure management

Tags: java

I am stuck trying to manager a list of list of lists. I have declared and initialized my data structure as so:

```
List<Vector<ArrayDeque<Vector_t>>> mData = new ArrayList<Vector<ArrayDeque<Vector_t>>>(
        6);

for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
    mData.add(i, new Vector<ArrayDeque<Vector_t>>());
    // mData.get(i).setSize(200);
}

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < 200; k++) {
        mData.get(i).add(new ArrayDeque<Vector_t>());
        mData.get(i).get(k).add(new Vector_t());
    }
}
```

where Vector_t is:

```
class Vector_t {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
}
```

Is this initialization correct? When adding values to the array deque at the last position, it replaces the whole arraydeque with the last element, and I have no idea why.

Also, when I changing values using the code `mdata.get(1).get(42)` the element at `mdata.get(0).get(40)` is also affected. Again, I have no idea why?

I have given hardcoded values for example..this is the way i m adding

```
if (mData.get(dir.value).get(slice).size() >= sMaxNum_c)
     {
                 mData.get(dir.value).get(slice).removeFirst();
     }
              mData.get(dir.value).get(slice).addLast(result.acc);
```

when adding values to one direction other direction values are changing...:(

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Sorry in the first line Class name is Vector_t...Typing mistake...Execuse me for that...!!

Comment: You know you can edit your post, right?

Comment: why don't you introduce some classes to encapsulate what you are doing instead of this!?

Comment: It has nothing to do with your initialization. There is something wrong with how you are changing the values in mdata.get(1).get(42).  How are you changing the values exactly?

Comment: It would be so greatful if can give me an example how can i do in that way... Thank u

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to either introduce some classes as Amir suggested, or at least make your code easier to understand by introducing some well-named, temporary local variables.
I don't know what you're trying to acheive, but re-writing with the use of some local variables might allow you to spot an issue:

```
List<Vector<ArrayDeque<Vector_t>>> mData = new ArrayList<Vector<ArrayDeque<Vector_t>>>(
        6);

for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
    mData.add(i, new Vector<ArrayDeque<Vector_t>>());
}

for (Vector nextVector : mData) {

    for (int k = 0; k < 200; k++) {
        ArrayDeque<Vector_t> tempArray = new ArrayDeque<Vector_t>());
        tempArray.add(new Vector_t());
        nextVector add(tempArray);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of what you are trying to achieve, but for starters, you should consider using another Data Structure besides Vector as it is obsolete.

```
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
// Consider using another DataStructure such as Arraylist, as Vector<> is obsolete.
import java.util.Vector;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Use diamond inference.
        List<Vector<ArrayDeque<Vector_t>>> mData = new ArrayList<>(6);

            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                Vector<ArrayDeque<Vector_t>> vav = new Vector<>();
                ArrayDeque<Vector_t> av = new ArrayDeque<>();

                for (int k = 0; k < 200; k++) {
                    av.add(new Vector_t(2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f));
                }

                vav.add(av);
            }
        }
    }
```

Use variables instead of calling get() so much.

```
public class Vector_t {
private float x;
private float y;
private float z;

public Vector_t() {
    x = 0.0f;
    y = 0.0f;
    z = 0.0f;
}

public Vector_t(float x, float y, float z) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.z = z;
}

public float GetX() {
    return x;
}

public float GetY() {
    return y;
}

public float GetZ() {
    return z;
}

public void SetX(float x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public void SetY(float y) {
    this.y = y;
}

public void SetZ(float z) {
    this.z = z;
}
```

}

use setters and getters for your class, it's all about using OOP programming concepts :)

If you are a little more specific on what you are trying to accomplish, I am sure we could help.

-Francisco

Comment: I am trying to bulid andorid app which gets sensor data in all the directions. Vector_t class is for x y z values in each direction.so the prob is values are nor storing properly in array deque as i have mentioned and when i am getting the values in one direction other direction values are effecting with this direction values.

Comment: Since when did Java's Vector become obsolete? I just checked Java 7 and it is not obsolete.